# express.json() is not parsing nested json object. it return [object Object] instead

Tags: node.js, json, express

express.json() is not parsing nested json object. it return [object Object] instead.

```
express - 4.17.1,
```

Request Headers

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

I m using express.json() as follows.

```
app.use(express.json());
```

when i post data without nested object. it works

```
const data = await this.$axios.$post(`user/update/${this.username}`, {confirmationCode:  "code"});
```

now req.body.confirmationCode is "code".

but if i post nested json object. It doesn't works

```
const data = await this.$axios.$post(`user/update/${this.username}`, {confirmationCode: { mobile: "code"}});
```

now req.body.confirmationCode.mobile is undefined.
and req.body.confirmationCode is [object Object].

Comment: Looks like you're converting `req.body.confirmationCode` to a string. `req.body.confirmationCode.toString()` -> `[object Object]`.

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that several people have downvoted this without actually answering the issue. I too had this as a problem and it turns out to be a simple fix. Try passing the object through JSON.stringify() and see if that helps.

example code:

```
`console.log(`My Test req.body:  ${JSON.stringify(req.body)} \n`);`
```

Also, if you are passing the JSON as an argument to a function, do not attempt to pass it plain text (in string format). Instead use it unadulterated as I did, req.body, or create a new object and send the variable of the object instead of the string version.